# Microsoft edge v 17.17134 displays a # on postback

Tags: microsoft-edge

I recently stumbled upon a weird problem with the last version of Microsoft Edge (17.17134).

I have a really simple classic asp form that posts data to another asp form. If I post a string which contains

> input

and

> onclick=""

the receiving page will only display a "#" even if the code behind seems ok(see screenshot)
[image]

here's a snippet:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="to.asp">
            <input type="text" name="hidInnerHTML" id="hidInnerHTML" style="width:500px;" value="steve would like your input on what to do when you activate the onclick= method" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="click me"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the code at the receiving end:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="border:1px solid red;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems that certain keyword in the post data will trigger this effect. IE, chrome, probably Firefox, previous version of edge - all work correctly.

Any clues or idea what is happening here?

I'll take all the help I can get! :)

Comment: I have just come across this issue on my asp.net webforms app. It is the same issue (using Edge 17.17134) but i have triggered it using either a <meta> or <a> tag in a textarea control which is then posted back to the server. From looking in the network tab in dev tools, it looks like the post occurs correctly and then a second (incorrect) get request is made which returns nothing in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a bit more research, i can see that this exact issue has just been raised here...

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/19045578/

Check out the link for a fuller explanation but the short story is that you either set a "X-XSS-Protection" response header on your site with a value of "0" or you wait for the Windows 10 Insider Preview version (Build 17758) of Edge which includes the fix for this bug.

Microsoft Edge 44.17758.1.0

Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17758